# How to run Github workflow only when the version in the package.json is different

Tags: npm, github-actions

I want to run Github workflow only when the version of the package has been bumped up.

after running `npm version patch` and push to GitHub I want to publish this new version. This's what I've tried but it still builds with every merge.

```
name: Publish test module

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
    paths:
      - packages/testmodule/package.json
      - '*.json'
      - .github/workflows/test.yml
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use the [github-action-npm-release](https://github.com/justincy/github-action-npm-release).

Here is a minimal example:

```yaml
name: Release
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build:
    name: Release
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
      - name: Release
        uses: justincy/github-action-npm-release@v1.2.0
        id: release
      - name: Print release output
        if: ${{ steps.release.outputs.released == 'true' }}
        run: echo Release ID ${{ steps.release.outputs.release_id }}
```

This action only concerns itself with checking if the `package.json` version has been updated or not. In case of doing a release, please use the [version-check](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/version-check) instead.